# Spring 5 upgrade issue ResourceServlet

Tags: java, spring, upgrade

I'm moving from spring 4 to spring 5 (no spring boot yet) and after finally resolving dependency hell (at least I think so) I have problem with deploying app to tomcat with such stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
... 18 more
```

I know that ResourceServlet is replaced with ResourceHttpRequestHandler but I cannot find place where I use in some way this ResourceServlet. Any idea how can I get rid of this is welcome.

Here is my web.xml for starters:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<distributable />
<display-name>app</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml WEB-INF/application-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- javamelody - web app monitoring tool -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jolokia-agent</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jolokia-agent</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jolokia/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>log4jwebtracker.servlet.TrackerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tracker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```